# Android ActionBar Progressbar position

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar with a 3 menu items. The last one of these is a refresh button.

The refresh button sets the...

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

... to true, which shows the spinning progress icon on the ActionBar. Great!

But the trouble is it shows it in front of all the other icons. I want it to the right of all the icons, so I can hide the refresh button so it looks like it replaces the refresh button when the spinner is visible.

How I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a custom ActionBar layout and position a Progress Bar (set to Indeterminate mode) wherever you want it. Then, instead of calling `setProgressBarVisibility(true)`, just call `ProgressBar.setVisibility()` based on whether you need to show the spinner or not.

Here's an example of my app's custom ActionBar layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_progress_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/search_view"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:queryHint="@string/menu_search_hint"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just tweak the position of the ProgressBar until it's where you want it. Then, in your Activity's `onCreate()` set the layout:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.activity_start_screen_actionbar);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: How does one get a reference to the progress bar? I have tried findviewbyid but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Mafro34 I do this in one of my fragments to get a reference to the ProgressBar: `ProgressBar progressSpinner = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_bar_progress_spinner);`. I imagine you can leave out the `getActivity()` if you're trying to find it from an Activity.

Comment: That didn't work for me, perhaps because i'm using the compat libs. I had to inflate the actionbar layout into a ViewGroup to access the members.